# How to deal with Nan values in swift

Tags: swift

I tried to get values of height for example

```swift
theta = // angle varies //

height = (147 - (88 * cos(theta)))
```

In return, I get `NaN` values.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in your `height` calculation that should generate a `NaN` unless you are passing a `NaN` into the `cos` function since `cos` is defined over the real numbers.  Something in your calculation for `theta` is probably generating a `NaN`.  You can add error checking code that detects bad numbers using the `isNaN` function.

In the code below I declare a custom error type, `MathErrors` which would indicate to a caller that the `theta` calculation yielded a bad number.  The `guard` error check notices the bad value with `isNaN` and throws the custom error when a bad `theta` value is discovered.

```
enum MathErrors : Error {
    case thetaIsNaN
}

var theta : Double = 0

guard !theta.isNaN else { print("Theta is NaN"); throw MathErrors.thetaIsNaN}
let height = 147 - (88 * cos(theta))
```

Comment: Hi Scott, this landed in my review queue because it's a code-only answer. I recognize that the question was not particularly well-formed, but it would be ideal if you could expand upon your answer to explain your suggested changes.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great.